# Does C# windows service takes time to start around 60-65 sec?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I designed a windows service in C#, and it takes time to start (60-70 sec). I was wondering does it generally take that long to start? It is my code which is taking that much time?

I have two threads which runs every 6 seconds and 1 minute.

And if it takes that much time, can somebody tell me why it takes that much time. Not in detail just an overview.

Comment: It depends on what you're running at the service onStart()

Then theres the general system performance, have you checked the start up time for other services.

Comment: Im just setting the timers and initializing them

Comment: Are you sure that there nothing else , like loops that check for disks sometimes looping through Diskdrives may cause the code to slow down, especially with flopy drives (i.e if you have them)

Comment: THere is one more thread which checks the data from DB but that is just on start.It doesn't have any interval

Answer (score 7):

If your service does alot of work during startup (`service.OnStart`), it will take a long time to start.

Defer the work to another thread if you want the service to startup immediatly.

This assumes that normal service startup is pretty much immediate.

Comment: Ony thing it does it sets up two timers to run every 6sec and 1 min.
And final thread checks the data from DB when the service is started.Do you think this could be reason?

Comment: The final thread checks the data and take action accordingly.Like sending mail etc.

Comment: Could very well be that last thread. Checking the DB and sending email can take a long time.

Comment: Exactly.I just commented out the last thread functionality and it started pretty fast.And when I uncommented out it started slowly as usal.

Answer (score 3):

Like Oded said,

```
     protected override void OnStart(string [] args)
  {
System.Threading.Thread workerThread =new System.Threading.Thread(longprocess());
workerThread.start();
  }

private void longprocess()
{
///long stuff
}
```

Although this will make your service to startup quickly it will not gurantee that longprocess() will be done quickly.